# Ansible playbook doesnt get values from inventory group_vars

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have got a simple playbook:

```
- hosts: all
  serial: 1
  order: "{{ run_order }}"
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - ping:
      register: resultt
```

My inventory tree:

```
.
├── group_vars
│   └── g1
│       └── values.yml
├── host_vars
└── inv
```

inv file:

```
[g1:children]
m1
m2

[g2:children]
m3
m4

[m1]
192.168.0.60

[m2]
192.168.0.61

[m3]
192.168.0.62

[m4]
192.168.0.63
```

group_vars/g1/values.yml:

```
---
run_order: 'reverse_sorted'
```

When I try to run playbook:

```
ansible-playbook -i inv-test/inv --limit='g1' my-playbook.yml
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR! The field 'order' has an invalid value, which includes an undefined variable. The error was: 'run_order' is undefined

The error appears to be in '/home/mk/throttle': line 1, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


- hosts: all
  ^ here
```

Although the output from `ansible-inventory -i inv --graph --vars` is correct

Why ansible doesn't parse vars from inventory groups_vars?
Ansible version 2.10.15

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you want to use a host variable in the scope of a play. See [Scoping variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#scoping-variables). It's possible if you create such a host variable first. Then you can use *hostvars* to reference the host variable. For example, given the simplified inventory

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
[g1]
host_01
host_02
```

and the *group_vars*

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/g1.yml 
run_order: 'reverse_sorted'
```

The playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: run_order
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i hosts pb.yml 

ok: [host_01] => 
  run_order: reverse_sorted
ok: [host_02] => 
  run_order: reverse_sorted
```

But, the playbook below

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  order: "{{ run_order }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: run_order
```

fails because the variable *run_order* is not defined in the scope of the play

> ERROR! The field 'order' has an invalid value, which includes an undefined variable. The error was: 'run_order' is undefined

The (awkward) solution is to create the *hostvars* in the first play and use it in the second play. For example, the second play in the playbook below is executed in the reverse order

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: run_order

- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  serial: 1
  order: "{{ hostvars.host_01.run_order }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: run_order
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i hosts pb.yml 

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [host_01] => 
  run_order: reverse_sorted
ok: [host_02] => 
  run_order: reverse_sorted

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [host_02] => 
  run_order: reverse_sorted

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [host_01] => 
  run_order: reverse_sorted
```